# Azure IoT Hub for CC3200 TI and Energia mac OS Sierra

Tags: macos, azure, arduino, iot

I need to connect my CC3200 Launchpad to IoT Hub from Energia. I followed a tutorial: https://github.com/farukc/AzureIoTHub-TI-CC3200, but this one is using CodeComposer which is not available for Mac OS. I run the CC3200 project in Energia, but on Serial Monitor Terminal I received a weird coded message:

> zÒrZzXBH(úXX{ÿFRBXþÂ@ÞXJJ,

and I have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Serial Monitor baud must be set on

> 115200 baud

. This change fixed my problem.

> Initializing TMP006 sensor ...  OK
>   Attempting to connect to Network named: TP-LINK_B08F
>   ..
>   You're connected to the network
>   Waiting for an ip address
>   ..
>   IP Address obtained